# Nginx の site-available は必要？

Tags: nginx

Nginx でサイトごとの設定をする際に、
site-available フォルダに hoge.com.conf というファイル名で設定を書き、
それを site-enable フォルダにシンボリックリンクを貼って、site-enableの
`*.conf`の設定を反映するという形にしております。
これはいくつかのサイトをこのやり方が定石というような形で書いてありました。
直接 site-enabled に書いてしまうことによる弊害はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

動きには特に弊害はありませんが、他の人が見たときに混乱する可能性はあります。

site-availableに本体を置いてsite-enabledにシンボリックリンクを張るのはたぶんApacheの設定ファイル由来の作法で、それに馴染んでいる人が多いと思いますので。

面倒だったら、こういうリンクを張ってくれるツールを使うと良いかも知れません。
https://github.com/perusio/nginx_ensite

自分は面倒なんで全てconf.dに入れちゃいますけどね・・・

Comment: conf.dにいれるのいいなと思いました、ありがとうございます。
僕が使っているAWSの設定もそのようになっていたので、そちらに合わせようと思います。

Answer (score 4):

`site-available` `site-enabled` はDebian系のApacheで使われていた慣習だと思うのですが、nginxだと他のディストリでもそれを勧める記事があるのですね・・・。

CentOSなどではそのディレクトリが用意されていないように、その構成を使わなければいけないということはありません。

[centos - nginx missing sites-available directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17413526/2818869)

他の人が見たときのわかりやすさも、その人がどちらの構成に慣れているかに依りますから。。

Comment: なるほど、Debian系のApacheの慣習なんですね。
僕はほとんどUbuntuとNginxしか使ったことがなく参考になります。
それぞれの慣習があるとのことなので、一旦conf.dに入れ込むことにします